# How can I run gedit with a different configuration

Tags: configuration, programming, startup, gedit, ide

I want to use gedit as a programming IDE and as a regular text editor. Would I be able to make some .desktop file to load a different configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be supported right now, see this [upstream bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=392023).

However, you could create a wrapper for gedit, that sets the specific plugins you want via gconftool-2.

This would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
old_config=$(gconftool-2 --get "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins")
gconftool-2 --set --type list --list-type string "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins" "[$1]"
gedit
gconftool-2 --set --type list --list-type string "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins" "$old_config"
```

Now save this somewhere as eg. gedit_profile and make it executable:

```
chmod +x  gedit_profile
```

To load different profiles, just call it with a comma-separated list of plugins you want to enable, for example:

```
/path/to/gedit_profile "terminal,colorpicker"
```

[Of course you then can put this into separate launchers.]

Comment: This works better for my needs: #!/bin/bash
normalConfig= gconftool-2 -g "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins"
gconftool-2 -s --type list --list-type string "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins" "[$1]"
gedit
gconftool-2 -s --type list --list-type string "/apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins" "[$normalConfig]"

Comment: Yeah, that's the advanced version (hence the "something like" part in my answer :P).

Comment: Setting values via gconf works for other options too (eg. color scheme)...  Because the new setting are effective immediately, just adding a couple of `External Tools` menu items (with optional shortcut keys) may suit (External Tools is a standard plugin)... I was interested in this because I like the idea of two instances of gedit with different colour settings, but I don't think that gedit allows concurrernt instances :(